# Sequence over heterogeneous list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-families, type-level-computation, data-kinds

Consider following definition of a `HList`:

```hs
infixr 5 :>
data HList (types :: [*]) where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  (:>) :: a -> HList l -> HList (a:l)
```

And a type family `Map` to map over typelevel lists:

```hs
type family Map (f :: * -> *) (xs :: [*]) where
    Map f '[] = '[]
    Map f (x ': xs) = (f x) ': xs
```

Now I would like to define `sequence` equivalence for `HList`s. My attempt looks like

```hs
hSequence :: Applicative m => HList (Map m ins) -> m (HList ins)
hSequence HNil = pure HNil
hSequence (x :> rest) = (:>) <$> x <*> hSequence rest
```

But I get errors like this:

```
Could not deduce: ins ~ '[]
       from the context: Map m ins ~ '[]
         bound by a pattern with constructor: HNil :: HList '[]
```

For me it looks like the compiler isn't sure that if `Map m` returns `[]` on some list then the list is empty. Sadly, I don't see any way to convince it to that fact. What should I do in this situation?

---

I am using GHC `8.6.5` with following extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
```

Answer (score 8):

First, there's an error here:

```
type family Map (f :: * -> *) (xs :: [*]) where
    Map f '[] = '[]
    Map f (x ': xs) = (f x) ': Map f xs
                             --^^^^^-- we need this
```

After that is fixed, the issue here is that we need to proceed by induction on `ins`, not on `Map f ins`. To achieve that, we need a singleton type:

```
data SList :: [*] -> * where
    SNil  :: SList '[] 
    SCons :: SList zs -> SList ( z ': zs )
```

and then an additional argument:

```
hSequence :: Applicative m => SList ins -> HList (Map m ins) -> m (HList ins)
hSequence SNil         HNil        = pure HNil
hSequence (SCons ins') (x :> rest) = (:>) <$> x <*> hSequence ins' rest
```

This now compiles. Matching on `SNil / SCons` refines `ins` to either `'[]` or `z ': zs`, so `Map m ins` can be unfolded one step as well. This allows us to make the recursive call.

As usual, we can remove the additional singleton argument through a suitable typeclass. I'm reasonably sure that some of this can be automated exploiting the `singletons` library.

```
class SingList ins where
    singList :: SList ins

instance SingList '[] where
    singList = SNil

instance SingList zs => SingList (z ': zs) where
    singList = SCons singList

hSequence2 :: (Applicative m, SingList ins)
              => HList (Map m ins) -> m (HList ins)
hSequence2 = hSequence singList
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem at all since I still need to create this `SList` that requires `ins` which I don't have in my hands.

Comment: @radrow See my last edit. IMO, this is the best we can achieve in Haskell, since we haven't full dependent types and `ins` is not present at runtime, so we can't pattern match on that unless we use a singleton argument (or a typeclass constraint `SingList ins` which provides it).

Answer (score 2):

This GADT preserves the spine ("length") of type level lists past type erasure:

```
data Spine (xs :: [k]) :: Type where
  NilSpine :: Spine '[]
  ConsSpine :: Spine xs -> Spine (x : xs)
```

From this, we can prove these lemmas:

```
mapNil' :: forall f xs. Map f xs ~ '[] => Spine xs -> xs :~: '[]
mapNil' NilSpine = Refl

type family Head (xs :: [k]) :: k where Head (x : _) = x
type family Tail (xs :: [k]) :: [k] where Tail (_ : xs) = xs
data MapCons f y ys xs =
  forall x xs'. (xs ~ (x : xs'), y ~ f x, ys ~ Map f xs') => MapCons
mapCons' :: forall f xs y ys. Map f xs ~ (y : ys) => Spine xs -> MapCons f y ys xs
mapCons' (ConsSpine _) = MapCons
```

Now, `Spine` is a singleton family: `Spine xs` has exactly one value for each `xs`. We can therefore erase it.

```
mapNil :: forall f xs. Map f xs ~ '[] => xs :~: '[]
mapNil = unsafeCoerce Refl -- safe because mapNil' exists
mapCons :: forall f xs y ys. Map f xs ~ (y : ys) => MapCons f y ys xs
mapCons = unsafeCoerce MapCons -- safe because mapCons' exists
```

These lemmas can then be used to define your function:

```
hSequence :: forall m ins. Applicative m => HList (Map m ins) -> m (HList ins)
hSequence HNil | Refl <- mapNil @m @ins = pure HNil
hSequence (x :> rest) | MapCons <- mapCons @m @ins = (:>) <$> x <*> hSequence rest
```

By starting with `Spine`, we can build a justification for why our logic works. Then, we can erase all the singleton junk we don't need at runtime. This is an extension of how we use types to build a justification for why our programs work, and then we erase them for the runtime. It's important to write `mapNil'` and `mapCons'` so we know what we're doing works.

Comment: Nice. I'd suggest to note that "`mapNil'` exists" is not enough to ensure safety. We also need it to be total -- without termination the unsafe stuff might be really unsafe. Ditto for `mapCons'`.

Comment: Btw, why do I need `mapNil'` here? Does the compiler need it somehow or is it just for the sake of formality? When I remove it everything seems to work, so why don't I just put `undefined` in the definition of `mapNil`?

Comment: @radrow For justification, yes. If you just `mapNil = unsafeCoerce Refl`, then you haven't proved that it's true. If you got its type wrong, you run the risk of segfaults and all that. If you write `mapNil'`, then you *know* what the type should be, so you don't have that risk.

Answer (score 2):

`HList` is quite an unwieldy type. I recommend using something like this one instead, which is similar to one from `vinyl`.

```
{-# language PolyKinds, DataKinds, GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes, TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Kind
import Control.Applicative

infixr 4 :>

-- Type is the modern spelling of the * kind
data Rec :: [k] -> (k -> Type) -> Type 
where
  Nil :: Rec '[] f
  (:>) :: f a -> Rec as f -> Rec (a ': as) f

htraverse
  :: forall (xs :: [k]) (f :: k -> Type) (g :: k -> Type) m.
     Applicative m
  => (forall t. f t -> m (g t))
  -> Rec xs f -> m (Rec xs g)
htraverse _f Nil = pure Nil
htraverse f (x :> xs) =
  liftA2 (:>) (f x) (htraverse f xs)
```

If you like, you can define

```
hsequence
  :: forall (xs :: [k]) (g :: k -> Type) m.
     Applicative m
  => Rec xs (Compose m g) -> m (Rec xs g)
hsequence = htraverse getCompose
```

Note that

```
HList xs ~= Rec xs Identity
```